# Angularjs - Get other properties of selected object on ng-change outside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am fairly new to Angularjs and I have come across a situation that no other questions seem to quite answer.

this is my **view**

```
<select id = "nameField" class = "form-control" ng-model = "name" ng-change = "fillDataType(userDefinedVariable)">
                <option ng-repeat = "userDefinedVariable in userDefinedWorkflowVariables">{{userDefinedVariable.name}}</option>
                </select>
```

This is my **controller**

```
$scope.userDefinedVariables = [{name:"object1",dataType:"number",description:"description1"},
{name:"object2",dataType:"number",description:"description2"}]


$scope.fillDataType = function(userDefinedVariable) {
   console.log(userDefinedVariable) //undefined
   var dataType = userDefinedVariable.dataType; //not working

}
```

Is there a way i can pass `"userDefinedVariable"` object to my `fillDataType`function as a parameter.

As a workaround, I am passing the `ng-model`(name) as a parameter to my `fillDataType` function and in that function Iam looping through `userDefinedVariables` to match the selected name, hence retrieving the object.

Is there no way I can access an object outside the ng-repeat scope? Or am I doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not use variable in ng-repeat outside of it.
But here there is another way to access selected object.You might want to take a look at ng-options directive.
You can replace code for looping by this

```
<select ng-options="userDefinedVariable as userDefinedVariable.name for userDefinedVariable  in userDefinedWorkflowVariables" ng-model="name"></select>
```

Then in in you will get complete object in `name` instead of just label.

Please run and check if it is working, if not I will try to create working code.

Comment: This lets me gain a hold of the entire object but i only want to store the name property in my ng-model and not the whole object. Only while passing it to the function, I wish to pass the whole object `userDefinedVariable`. Is there a way?

Comment: I could see any other way to achieve this, but ti does not make any difference memory wise if you are concerned about that as it store object as reference. And if you want show name somewhere you can just access it from whole object.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can select whole object in ng-model instead of single name property of object `userDefinedVariables`. Try following code..

`<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="item as item.name for item in userDefinedWorkflowVariables" ng-change = "fillDataType(selectedName)">
</select>`

Comment: Why pass `selectedName` as an argument if it is attached to `$scope`?

Comment: passing parameter to function is always better approach as same function can be used from anywhere. Suppose on `ng-change` calling for api service and same can be used where that particular service is required. if we have not pass data then also it can be done again checking for property set or not came into picture.

Answer (score 0):

use ng-options

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <select id="nameField" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedOption" ng-change="fillDataType()" ng-options="obj.name for obj in userDefinedWorkflowVariables">
                    
                    </select>
                    
                    

    </div>



    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.selectedOption={};
        
       $scope.userDefinedWorkflowVariables = [{name:"object1",dataType:"number",description:"description1"},
    {name:"object2",dataType:"number",description:"description2"}]

    $scope.selectedOption =$scope.userDefinedWorkflowVariables[0]


    $scope.fillDataType = function() {
       console.log( $scope.selectedOption) 
       var dataType =  $scope.selectedOption.dataType;

    }
    });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why pass `selectedOption` as an argument if it is attached to `$scope`?

Comment: I do not wish to set my `ng-model` to the entire `selectedVariable`. Just the name. The entire object only to pass to the `ng-change`